# How to post array key from .net/C# to php

Tags: c#, php, .net

I need to convert my `Dictionary<string,string>` into a php array key like the following:

```
$result['iv'] = iv;
$result['json'] = pJSON;
$result['header'] = header;
```

I then need to post it to a target server which is using php.

How would I do this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942427/posting-arrays-in-webclient-c-net

Answer (score 1):

Why not convert it into a more universally recognised format?

I suggest [JSON using C#](http://www.json.org/) (see C# list of JSON libraries near the bottom of the page) and then in PHP you can use:

```
$result = json_decode($_POST['result'], true);
```

Comment: yep i know that is a way better way of doing things, however we have no control on php side so far