# Can not pass a list of strings to a Web API endpoint. Why?

Tags: list, asp.net-core, post, parameters, httpclient

Can not pass a list of strings to a Web API endpoint. Why?

Here is my controller:

```
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class MyController
{
    [HttpPost("foo")]
    public string MyMethod(List<string> strs)
    {
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

Here is how I am trying to call it:

```
var strs = new List<string> { "bar" };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(strs);
var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = await httpCliet.PostAsync("/My/foo", content);
```

Before calling the endpoint I place a breakpoint on the `return "foo";` line. Once the breakpoint is hit the `strs` list inside the `MyController.MyMethod` is empty. The `strs` is not null, but it contains no elements. While my intentions and expectations are to see the `strs` containing one element, i.e. the string `"bar"`.

I am using the ASP.NET Core 2.2 in project where I create and use the `HttpClient`. And I am using the same ASP.NET Core 2.2 in project where I have the endpoint.

I am not sure what is wrong here. I have checked a few sources. E.g. the following:

[C# HTTP post , how to post with List<XX> parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28042830/c-sharp-http-post-how-to-post-with-listxx-parameter)

https://carldesouza.com/httpclient-getasync-postasync-sendasync-c/

https://blog.jayway.com/2012/03/13/httpclient-makes-get-and-post-very-simple/

And I can not find what I am missing according to those resources.

**UPDATE**

The following call works for me as expected:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(string.Empty);
var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = await server.CreateClient().PostAsync("/My/foo?strs=bar", content);
```

Maybe someone knows why the parameters in my case are read from the query string only, but not from body?

Comment: Using your code, I seem to get the call in the api, so might be your machine?

Comment: I am not sure. But thank you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your url to a full url in `client.PostAsync`.Here is a demo worked:

Api(localhost:44379):

WeatherForecastController:

```
[HttpPost("foo")]
        public string MyMethod(List<string> strs)
        {
            return "foo";
        }
```

Call(localhost:44326):

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CheckAsync() {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var strs = new List<string> { "bar","bar1","bar2" };
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(strs);
            var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var response = await client.PostAsync("https://localhost:44379/WeatherForecast/foo", content);
            return Ok(response);
        }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you. I will check a few things on my side and get back to accepting your answer.

Comment: I have updated my question. Could you check it, please?

Comment: Maybe the updated details will mean something to you. Because for me it is really very confusing. :)

Comment: I was not able to solve my problem. But I will accept your answer. Since, it seems that the issue is very particular to my environment. So, outside help seems to be not a feasible opportunity. Thank you and have a nice day.