# How to post List<T> through HttpClient?

Tags: c#, httpclient, webapi

I've studied a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28042830/c-sharp-http-post-how-to-post-with-listxx-parameter) and tried to use it in my own case (Blazor Server App). I have the following code:

```
public async static Task HttpPostAsync(List<Equipment> eqs)
    {
    var myObject = (dynamic)new JsonObject();
    myObject.List = eqs;
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var data = new StringContent(myObject.toString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var response = await 

client.PostAsync("https://localhost:7002/api/ApiEquipment/EquipmentStatusOn", data);
}
```

When I run the code, I see the following error in the browser console:

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException:
> 'System.Text.Json.Nodes.JsonObject' does not contain a definition for
> 'List'    at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , List`1 )
> at
> System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite
> site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)

How can I fix that?

**Update:**

My api code is:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> EquipmentStatusOn([FromBody] List<Equipment> eqs)
{
    foreach (var item in eqs)
    {
        item.IsActive = true;
    }
    await _sqlServerContext.BulkUpdateAsync(eqs, config => config.BatchSize = 200);
    await _sqlServerContext.BulkSaveChangesAsync();

    return Ok(eqs);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you're getting relates to `myObject.List = eqs`. You've cast to a dynamic to prevent build errors, but this results in the runtime error you're getting.
You'll need to encode the list into JSON, you can use the built-in JsonContent class to handle this for you.

```
var myObject = new { List = eqs };
var client = new HttpClient();
using var data = JsonContent.Create(myObject)
var response = await client.PostAsync("https://localhost:7002/api/ApiEquipment/EquipmentStatusOn", data)
```

Comment: I tested this code. The response return status code of 400 (Bad Request).

Comment: With your edits it looks like it takes an array directly, not an object with a property called `List`. Try sending through `JsonContent.Create(eqs)` instead

Comment: I used `using var data = JsonContent.Create(eqs);`. The response is still 400.

Comment: I would try to call the endpoint via another tool (such as Postman) to get your request correct, then rebuild that request in C#.

Comment: If asp.net has rejected your call with a BadRequest the returned body should contain details why.

Comment: Do we need to set `Encoding.UTF8` and `application/json` in headers? How can I add them in the final code?

Comment: These are the defaults if not provided. You can read more about JSON Content here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.jsoncontent.create